# Return the intersection geometry from a GeoServer WFS service

Tags: geoserver, wfs, intersection

The behavior I'm looking for

1. Suppose I have a layer called 'states' in GeoServer exposed as a WFS. With the attributes 'name' and 'geometry'. Ex: Name: 'Texas', Geometry: 'a polygon representing Texas'
2. I send a WFS request sending a polygon
3. GeoServer returns the states that intersects the polygon **and the intersection geometry** (operation similar to ST_Intersection in PostGIS).

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems promising https://www.igismap.com/wps-split-polygon-geoserver/. WFS does not process data despite re-projecting. Web Processing Service WPS is for processing.

Comment: Thanks... I was aware of WPS, but I was trying to avoid it.. But It looks like it's the only option